# Using WxWidgets with Eclipse for C++

Tags: eclipse, wxwidgets

I installed wxWidgets and then followed the instructions to make it with MSYS. After it was done, I copied a sample from a site and put it on a project in eclipse. The code was:

```
#include <wx/string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  wxPuts(wxT("A wxWidgets console application"));
}
```

But when I compile I get this error:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project test2 ****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****

g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\test2.o ..\src\test2.cpp
..\src\test2.cpp:9:23: wx/string.h: No such file or directory
..\src\test2.cpp: In function `int main(int, char**)':
..\src\test2.cpp:13: error: `wxT' was not declared in this scope
..\src\test2.cpp:13: error: `wxPuts' was not declared in this scope
..\src\test2.cpp:13: warning: unused variable 'wxT'
..\src\test2.cpp:13: warning: unused variable 'wxPuts'
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 78  ms.
```

What did I do wrong?

---

I edited the settings but I still get this.
There is no -I still..

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project Wx1 ****
**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\simple.o ..\src\simple.cpp
In file included from ..\src\simple.cpp:1:
..\src\simple.h:1:19: wx/wx.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ..\src\simple.cpp:1:
..\src\simple.h:4: error: expected class-name before '{' token
..\src\simple.h:6: error: expected `,' or `...' before '&' token
..\src\simple.h:6: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `wxString' with no type
..\src\simple.cpp:3: error: expected `,' or `...' before '&' token
..\src\simple.cpp:4: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `wxString' with no type
..\src\simple.cpp: In constructor `Simple::Simple(int)':
..\src\simple.cpp:4: error: class `Simple' does not have any field named `wxFrame'
..\src\simple.cpp:4: error: `NULL' was not declared in this scope
..\src\simple.cpp:4: error: `wxID_ANY' was not declared in this scope
..\src\simple.cpp:4: error: `title' was not declared in this scope
..\src\simple.cpp:4: error: `wxDefaultPosition' was not declared in this scope
..\src\simple.cpp:4: error: `wxSize' was not declared in this scope
..\src\simple.cpp:6: error: `Centre' was not declared in this scope
..\src\simple.cpp:6: warning: unused variable 'Centre'
..\src\simple.cpp:4: warning: unused variable 'NULL'
..\src\simple.cpp:4: warning: unused variable 'wxID_ANY'
..\src\simple.cpp:4: warning: unused variable 'title'
..\src\simple.cpp:4: warning: unused variable 'wxDefaultPosition'
..\src\simple.cpp:4: warning: unused variable 'wxSize'
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 63  ms.
```

Here is a screenshot
[screenshot http://imgkk.com/i/aRjvDe.jpg](http://imgkk.com/i/aRjvDe.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you didn't set the correct include directories to find the wx headers (There is no -I... on the compiler command line).

You could add include directories in the project settings of a CDT project under C++->Settings->GNU C++->Include directories (or similar I don't have Eclipse running at the moment so the names way vary).

**EDIT:**

You have changed the "GCC Assembler" include paths. Since you don't program assembler this part isn't used. You need to edit the include paths in the "GCC C++ Compiler" path!

Comment: I did the last thing you said but now I get a load of errors like "<thing's name here> is not defined."

Comment: Since I don't know anything about wxWidgets I can only guess but maybe you missed to include some necessary files or the wxWidget stuff is located in an own namespace (if wxWidget is C++ and not plain C) so you have to use <namespace>::wxPuts(...) or using <namespace>; in your main.cpp.

Comment: And what's the way to know the namespace it's in? Sorry, I'm a newbie

Comment: It must be in the documentation. When looking at the examples from the wxWidgets homepage it seems that wxWidgets doesn't use a specific namespace but prefixes all symbols with "wx".
So there must be some missing header files (you included "wx/string.h" and I assume that you need to include more to get wxPuts() to work. Take a look at the examples on the the wxWidgets homepage, they should be helpful).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the guide [here](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Eclipse%2C_CDT_%26_MingW_%26_MSYS_Setup_Guide) might help you, as you have already built this library I guess you only read for the section titled *Verification that wxWidgets Libraries Are Working* onwards.